# Trying to automatically refresh from JSON with knockoutjs

Tags: jquery, json, knockout.js

I'm trying to use an AJAX JSON request to automatically refresh the data displayed on a page with the latest values from the server.

Here's my javascript:

```
function ExampleViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.ExampleData = ko.observableArray([]);

    $.getJSON("/JSONExample", function (allData) {
        var mappeddata = $.map(allData, function (item){
            return new DataItem(item)
        });
        self.ExampleData(mappeddata);
    })

    window.setTimeout(ExampleViewModel, 5000);
}

function DataItem(data) {
    //console.log(data);
    this.Name = ko.observable(data.Name);
    this.Price = ko.observable(data.Price);
}

ko.applyBindings(new ExampleViewModel());
```

And here's my HTML:

```
<div id="knockout">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th><th>Price</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: ExampleData">
            <tr>
                <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: Price"></td>
            </tr>    
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

It's correctly pulling the JSON and it displays correctly on the first iteration. The output looks like this:

```
Name        Price
Item1       $150.00
Item2       $20.00
Item3       $99.99
```

On subsequent iterations, it pulls the JSON, and if I change the data on the server (say if I change the price of Item1 to $200.00), it does get the updated data in the JSON. However, the UI doesn't refresh - it just displays the initial data until I refresh the whole page.

I believe I'm misunderstanding something about how the knockout bindings work, or else my approach is totally off for what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checkout [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gurkavcu/rsvLj/)

You have to keep instance of ExampleViewModel and use that instance for everything.

```
function getRandomData() {
    return [{
        "Name": "Apple",
        "Price": (Math.random()*10)+1},
    {
        "Name": "Orange",
        "Price":(Math.random()*10)+1},
    {
        "Name": "Banana",
        "Price": (Math.random()*10)+1},
    {
        "Name": "Melon",
        "Price": (Math.random()*10)+1}];
}

function ExampleViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.ExampleData = ko.observableArray([]);    
    self.update = function() {
          $.ajax("/echo/json/", {
            data: {
                json: ko.toJSON(getRandomData())
            },
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(allData) {        
                var mappeddata = $.map(allData, function (item){
                    return new DataItem(item)
                });
                self.ExampleData(mappeddata);
            }
        }); 
    }  
}

function DataItem(data) {
    //console.log(data);
    this.Name = ko.observable(data.Name);
    this.Price = ko.observable(data.Price);
}

var exampleViewModel = new ExampleViewModel();
window.setInterval(exampleViewModel.update,1000);
ko.applyBindings(exampleViewModel);
```

Also beware of using this keyword directly inside the callback function of setTimeout & Interval. Use 'self' instead. Checkout [this problem part](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout#The_%27this%27_problem)

Comment: Ah now I get what I was doing wrong. This worked like a charm thanks!